# Google sign-in for website example broken in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-signin, google-identity

I've been having a lot of problem with sign-in to picassa and one issue appears to be that sign in using platform.js is broken in the latest Firefox.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Works fine in Chrome. No surprise there. Also OK on Edge

But on Firefox it fails in platform.js on load with securityErrors. And using the signin button the callback never gets called.

here's the erros and stacktraces in fri the FFx console

I'm serving on http locally but have seen same erros when remote https.

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
hasLocalStorage()
iframe:59
<anonymous>
iframe:82
<anonymous>
iframe:1
insertScript()
supercookie.js:32
<anonymous>
supercookie.js:146
load()
sandbox.js:66
importScripts()
sandbox.js:326
WorkerSandbox()
sandbox.js:287
bound call()
self-hosted
constructor()
heritage.js:146
initialize()
worker-child.js:52
bound call()
self-hosted
constructor()
heritage.js:146
createWorker()
page-mod.js:156
onContent()
page-mod.js:189
onContentWindow()
page-mod.js:121
bound onContentWindow()
self-hosted
iframe:59

GET https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/2748322407-idpiframe.js [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
w.prototype.pa()
2748322407-idpiframe.js:6
h.start()
2748322407-idpiframe.js:42
sb()
2748322407-idpiframe.js:76
<anonymous>
iframe:1
```

Comment: Which version of Firefox / which OS are you running? I tried it on FF49 on Ubuntu and OS X and it worked.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had specified Windows 10 and FFx 49.01. Edge gives a bunch of syntax errors but seems to work.

Comment: same when I use client:platform.js. What is the difference between the 2 version of the script?